# How to use kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project=true

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Long ago, when Kotlin version 1.3.20 was released (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/01/kotlin-1-3-20-released/), the ability to build in parallel using Gradle Workers was added. Simply adding the kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project = true setting does not give any gain in build speed. As far as I understand, this parameter can be useful only if I have several folders with classes independent of each other within the same project. I saw the use of this setting when assembling the gradle itself, but did not see anywhere that separate source sets were created for each folder.
Could you provide examples of how to correctly describe the build process in build.gradle.kts so that mentioned option is really used and gives an increase in build speed when there are several processor cores.

Answer (score 0):

As of yet, there's no simple way to parallelize compilation of a single source set containing Kotlin code (like just the `main` sources), as the compiler has to analyze all of the sources together and resolve cross-references within the source set.

By default, without any additional options, Gradle runs compilation of Kotlin sources in parallel only in different subprojects. The option `kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project` also allows Gradle to run parallel compilation tasks in one project, but that only works for different source sets (that don't depend on each other!), or different targets.

For example, in multiplatform projects, if you have several targets, `kotlin.parallel.tasks.in.project` allows Gradle to build the compilation outputs (JVM/Android classes, `*.js`, Kotlin/Native `*.klib`s and binaries) in parallel. In Android projects, if you build multiple product variants, this option also allows parallel Kotlin compilation for those variants.

In simpler project layouts, where you only have `main` and `test` source sets and a single target, there's no way to improve Kotlin compilation speed by using multiple processors, unless you split one project into several projects.

Comment: My project has several folders "main", "main1", "main2" with sources that are independent of each other. These sources are generated at the build stage before starting to compile the project. Due to the fact that they are generated, I cannot divide them into different projects. The question is - how to correctly indicate to Kotlin that there are several folders with a set of sources? Any samples?